# What is wrong with this login script?

Tags: php, session, authentication

I don't know why this PHP login script isn't working. When i try to log in it always returns: "Ongeldig wachtwoord/gebruikersnaam!".

This is the script:

```
session_start();
include('connect.php');

// functie voor random key
function make_rand($length) {
  $chars = "aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ1234567890";
  $rand = '';
  for ($i = 1; $i <= $length; $i++) {
    $num = rand(0, strlen($chars));
    $rand .= substr($chars, $num, 1);
    }
 return $rand;
  }
```

This function creates a random key to use as a session_id.

```
// kijk of formulier is verzonden
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {     // indien verzonden
  $query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name = '" .$_POST['inlognaam'] . "'");
```

Server checks if username exists..

```
if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {    // als er een gebruiker is gevonden
    $user = mysql_fetch_object($query);
    if ($user->password == isset($_POST['password'])) {  
      $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->name;
      $rand_key = make_rand(50);    // maak een random string voor sessie session_id mbv van functie
      $_SESSION['session_id'] = $rand_key;
      // zet de sessie id in de db zodat we hem later kunnen controleren
      mysql_query("UPDATE customers SET session_id = '" . $rand_key . "' WHERE name = '" . $_SESSION['inlognaam'] . "'");
  $_SESSION['user_ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADRESS'];
  echo 'Inloggen is gelukt!';
  }
```

When the user exists, the server creates a session_id, saves the users ip address in user_ip and it also saves the username (user_id)

```
else {  // ongeldig wachtwoord
  echo 'Ongeldig wachtwoord/gebruikersnaam!';
  }
} else {  // ongeldige gebruikersnaam
echo 'Ongeldig wachtwoord/gebruikersnaam!';
}
  }
```

If user doesn't exist it echo's: Ongeldig gebruikersnaam/wachtwoord" (invalid username/password).

```
 else {
    echo '<table id="loginbox">';
    echo '<tr><td><b>Login:</b></td></tr>';
    echo '<form action="test.php" method=\"post\">';
    echo '<tr><td>Gebruikersnaam:</td></tr><tr><td> &nbsp;<input style="width:120;" name="inlognaam" type="text" id="inlognaam"> </td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td>Wachtwoord:</td></tr><tr><td> &nbsp;<input type="password" style="width:120;" name="password id="password"> </td></tr>';
    echo '<tr><td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td></tr>';
    echo '</table>';
}
```

This is the login form.

**EDIT:** I just noticed that it doesn't even use the PHP script, it just writes the content of the input to the URL..

ex.:

```
localhost/School/test.php?inlognaam=Thomas&password=british9&Submit=Login
```

Comment: What does your generated SQL query look like? Does it work when you run it in the database?

Comment: The generated SQL should become this: `"SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name = 'Thomas'"`

Comment: What happens when a customer called `Thomas O'Connor` comes along?

Comment: than his username is Thomas2? :P

Comment: You really, really want to look up SQL injection.

Comment: I will do that when I've fixed this!

Comment: How can it doesn't use the php script if you comment "This stops it from giving the "user does not exist" error but it still doesn't echo "u bent ingelogd". It just seems to refresh the page and that's it.. " on @Bart Friederichs's answer ?

Comment: That's a good question. I think it does both then, because `method="post"`

Answer (score 3):

Probably the problem is here:

```
if ($user->password == isset($_POST['password']))
```

Quick fix:

```
if ($user->password == $_POST['password'])
```

`isset` returns a boolean telling if the array item is set, not the value of the item.

Also, in your form, it says

```
name="password
```

which should be:

```
name="password"
```

Besides that, there is some more to say about your code:

1. Do not use `$_POST[]` directly in an SQL query, **always** escape it.
2. Use `array_key_exists` to check if a certain key exists in `$_POST`. `isset()` will generate warnings.
3. sessions have a unique id, no need to generate it like this (which is by the way not guaranteed to be unique, check out UUIDs for better unique IDs)

Comment: This stops it from giving the "user does not exist" error but it still doesn't echo "u bent ingelogd". It just seems to refresh the page and that's it..

Comment: Your form is broken as well. It misses a " after the field name of the password.

Answer (score 0):

when you are checking password you are comparing user password value with the true or false return value of isset

Answer (score 0):

You never set `$_SESSION['inlognaam']`, so try to replace :

```
mysql_query("UPDATE customers SET session_id = '" . $rand_key . "' WHERE name = '" . $_SESSION['inlognaam'] . "'");
```

With :

```
mysql_query("UPDATE customers SET session_id = '" . $rand_key . "' WHERE name = '" . $_POST['inlognaam'] . "'");
```

**EDIT :** 
Or set `$_SESSION['inlognaam']` before the query :

```
$_SESSION['inlognaam'] = $_POST['inlognaam'];
mysql_query("UPDATE customers SET session_id = '" . $rand_key . "' WHERE name = '" . $_SESSION['inlognaam'] . "'");
```

**EDIT 2 :**
To debug, I would try to simplify the code :

```
<?php
include('connect.php');  

// kijk of formulier is verzonden
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    // indien verzonden
    $query= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE name = '" .$_POST['inlognaam'] . "'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        // als er een gebruiker is gevonden
        $user = mysql_fetch_object($query);
        if ($user->password == $_POST['password']) {
            echo 'Inloggen is gelukt!';
        } else {
            // ongeldig wachtwoord
            echo 'Ongeldig wachtwoord/gebruikersnaam!';
        }
    } else {
        // ongeldige gebruikersnaam
        echo 'Ongeldig wachtwoord/gebruikersnaam!';
    }
}else {
?>
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <table id="loginbox">
        <tr><td><b>Login:</b></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Gebruikersnaam:</td></tr>
        <tr><td> &nbsp;<input type="text" style="width:120;" name="inlognaam" id="inlognaam"> </td></tr>
        <tr><td>Wachtwoord:</td></tr>
        <tr><td> &nbsp;<input type="password" style="width:120;" name="password" id="password"> </td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login"></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```